# Android edittext input money format only

Tags: android, keyboard, format, decimal, currency

I have 1 Edittext. When the user click on it, it will bring up the keyboard. How can I set the keyboard to number WITH the dot(for decimal) together? I don't want the user to switch the keyboard to enter the dot.

I have tried `android:inputType="phone"` and `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` but the dot is separated from the numeric keyboard.

Comment: Another way (I am currently facing the same issue): 1. Write your own keyboard or make two separate fields for fractions. For instance: The value 20,50 € (currency does not matter) would be split into two fields: one for 20 and one for the 50 cents. Of course the downside is, the user would have to advance to another field to enter the fraction.

Comment: follow-up: The separate field stuff looks fairly ugly (I tried it) so I am now thinking about writing a fake keyboard using linear layout etc... Since I need the dot and the comma as well as the numbers. However my SII keyboard's comma is called "Pause" (Android standard keyboard) no way in hell any user could guess that oO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't as it seems the exact layout and how it corresponds to the inputType parameter is highly dependent on the keyboard implementation, version and most likely language.

For example on my Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.1, with Swiftkey X keyboard, German language I have bit '.' and ',' on the numeric keyboard (numberDecimal)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm currently testing it on eclipse android 2.2 as I don't have a android phone with me now.

Comment: when you used that like numberDecimal .should "," working in German instead of "." . Is it working or not?